# Prove the following function is PDF of a uniform random variable.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $f_i(x) (1\le i\le n)$ is PDF of a continous uniform random variable defined as follows:

$$f_i(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{b_i-a_i} & a_i\le x\le b_i,\\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

now prove that the following $f(x)$ is PDF of a continous uniform random variable, suppose that all the random variables are independent.

$$f(x)=\dfrac{f_1(x)f_2(x)....f_n(x)}{\int_ {-\infty} ^{\infty}  f_1(y)f_2(y)....f_n(y) dy} $$

In other words, find a and b such that:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{b-a} & a\le x\le b,\\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Pick your _favorite_ real number (let's call it $c$). Does  $f(c)$ equal $0$? Why or why not?

Comment: "suppose that all the random variables are independent." Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Is $x$ a vector $(x_1,x_2...x_n)$ or a single real number?

Answer (score 2):

The OP seems ill-defined (for instance, I cannot see why $\int_ {-\infty} ^{\infty}  f_1(y)f_2(y)....f_n(y) dy{}\neq{}0$), however I will attempt a plausible answer.

Suppose that we have a collection of $n$ independent, Uniformly distributed random variables with associated domains $\left[a_i\,,\,b_i\right]$ (for $i{}={}1,\ldots,n$). Further, suppose that these domains overlap, so that there exists real numbers $l$ and $u$ (with $l{}<{}u$) such that

$$
\left[l\,,\,u\right]{}={}\bigcap\limits_{i}\left[a_i, b_i\right] \,.
$$

Then, for $x{}\in{}\left[l\,,\,u\right]$, we have
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{f_1(x)f_2(x)....f_n(x)}{\int_ {-\infty} ^{\infty}  f_1(y)f_2(y)....f_n(y) dy}{}={}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_{i}\left[a_i, b_i\right]}}{\dfrac{(u-l)}{\prod\limits_{i}\left[a_i, b_i\right]}}{}={}\dfrac{1}{u-l}\,.
$$

And, for $x{}\notin{}\left[l\,,\,u\right]$, we have
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{f_1(x)f_2(x)....f_n(x)}{\int_ {-\infty} ^{\infty}  f_1(y)f_2(y)....f_n(y) dy}{}={}\dfrac{0}{\dfrac{(u-l)}{\prod\limits_{i}\left[a_i, b_i\right]}}{}={}0\,.
$$

Thus, $f(x)$ defines the density of a uniformly distributed random variable over the interval $\left[l\,,\,u\right]$.